# Columnas de una tabla con un un tamaño determinado

Tags: html, css, mpdf

Estoy tratando de realizar una tabla que tenga un tamaño fijo en cuanto a sus filas (conservando su tamaño), pero que sus columnas se adapte al tamaño de una página sin la necesidad de utilizar `JavaScript` para generar dicho efecto, porque lo que estoy haciendo es una tabla en un reporte de PDF con la respectiva librería de [mPDF](https://mpdf.github.io/) por lo que solo puedo hacer uso de efectos algo limitados con `CSS`.

**LO QUE PRETENDO**

Es solo una imagen de lo que pretendo (gracias a PAINT):
[image: Tabla1]

---

**LO QUE TENGO**

Es lo que he generado, pero el problema surge porque se debe hacer uso de toda la página de un documento PDF con tamaño CARTA.
[image: Tabla2]

**CÓDIGO**

```html
<style>
    .text-left
    {
      text-align:left;
    }

    .text-right
    {
      text-align:right;
    }

    .text-center
    {
      text-align:center;
    }
    .table-factura
    {
      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
      background-color: transparent;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
      padding: .3rem;

      text-align: center;
      font-size: 12px;
      font-family: Arial;
      line-height: 1.2;
      color: #444;
    }

    .table-item
    {
      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0;
      padding: .3rem;
      border: 1px solid #dee2e6;

      text-align: center;
      font-size: 12px;
      font-family: Arial;
      line-height: 1.2;
    }

    .table-item-prueba
    {
      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      width: 100%;
      table-layout: fixed;
      max-width: 100%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0;
      padding: .3rem;
      border: 1px solid #dee2e6;

      text-align: center;
      font-size: 12px;
      font-family: Arial;
      line-height: 1.2;
    }

    .thead-primary
    {
      background-color: #007bff !important;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      font-size: 12px;
      font-family: Arial;
      line-height: 1.2;
    }

    .table-striped tr:nth-child(even)
    {
      background-color: #f2f2f2
    }

    .tr-calculos
    {
      padding: 0.1rem;
    }

    .td-calculos
    {
      border-right: 1px solid #dee2e6;
      border-left: 1px solid #dee2e6;
    }

    .td-legal
    {
      background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242) !important;
      border: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
    }

  </style>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <table class="table-factura">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-center" colspan="5" style="border: 1px solid #dee2e6;">
          <strong>FACTURA DE VENTA - XXXXXX</strong>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center" colspan="2">
          <strong>N°. XXXXX</strong>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table-factura">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-left" colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid #dee2e6;">
          <strong>CLIENTE</strong>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid #dee2e6;">
          XXXXXX XXX
        </td>
        <td class="text-center" colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid #dee2e6;">
          <strong>NIT</strong>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center" colspan="3" style="border: 1px solid #dee2e6;">
          XXXXXXXX
        </td>
        <td class="text-center" colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid #dee2e6;">
          <strong>TELÉFONO</strong>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center" colspan="3" style="border: 1px solid #dee2e6;">
          XXXXXXXX
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-left" colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid #dee2e6;">
          <strong>RAZÓN</strong>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" colspan="2">
          XXXXXX XXXXX
        </td>
        <td class="text-center" colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid #dee2e6;">
          <strong>FECHA</strong>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center" colspan="3" style="border: 1px solid #dee2e6;">
          XXXX-XX-XX
        </td>
        <td class="text-center" colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid #dee2e6;">
          <strong>VENCE</strong>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center" colspan="3" style="border: 1px solid #dee2e6;">
          XXXX-XX-XX
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-left" colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid #dee2e6;">
          <strong>DIRECCIÓN</strong>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" colspan="6" style="border: 1px solid #dee2e6;">
          XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        </td>
        <td class="text-center" colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid #dee2e6;">
          <strong>CIUDAD</strong>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center" colspan="3" style="border: 1px solid #dee2e6;">
          XXXXXXX, XXXXXXXX
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-left" colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid #dee2e6;">
          <strong>Nota:</strong>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center" colspan="10" style="border: 1px solid #dee2e6;">

        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table class="table-item table-striped">
    <tr class="thead-primary">
      <th scope="col" style="color: #ffffff">#</th>
      <th class="text-left" scope="col" style="color: #ffffff">Código</th>
      <th class="text-left" scope="col" style="color: #ffffff">Producto</th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-center" style="color: #ffffff">Cantidad</th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-center" style="color: #ffffff">Descuento (%)</th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-center" style="color: #ffffff">IVA (%)</th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-right"  style="color: #ffffff">Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">
          1
        </th>
        <td class="text-left">
          COD003
        </td>
        <td class="text-left">
          LENOVO C40-30
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          1
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          0%
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          19%
        </td>

        <!--Calculos de facturacion-->
        <td class="text-right">
          $1,260,000
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">
          1
        </th>
        <td class="text-left">
          COD003
        </td>
        <td class="text-left">
          LENOVO C40-30
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          1
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          0%
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          19%
        </td>

        <!--Calculos de facturacion-->
        <td class="text-right">
          $1,260,000
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">
          1
        </th>
        <td class="text-left">
          COD003
        </td>
        <td class="text-left">
          LENOVO C40-30
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          1
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          0%
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          19%
        </td>

        <!--Calculos de facturacion-->
        <td class="text-right">
          $1,260,000
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">
          1
        </th>
        <td class="text-left">
          COD003
        </td>
        <td class="text-left">
          LENOVO C40-30
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          1
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          0%
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          19%
        </td>

        <!--Calculos de facturacion-->
        <td class="text-right">
          $1,260,000
        </td>
      </tr>
      <br>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He mirado la documentación y me he visto que los estilos inline `<style> </style>` los omite en el caso de las tablas.

> Block-level tags (DIV, P etc) are ignored inside tables, including any CSS styles - inline CSS or stylesheet classes, id etc. To set text characteristics within a table/cell, either define the CSS for the table/cell, or use in-line tags e.g.
>
> https://mpdf.github.io/tables/table-layout.html
>
> https://mpdf.github.io/tables/tables.html

Prueba a poner los estilos en la tag del HTML, por ejemplo `<table style="width: 100%">`